# sum dates values based on custom quarters

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have the following data :

[image: Data to sum]

What I want to achieve using SQL, is summing the `Montant` column, based on quarter ranges (3 months increment) where these quarters start at a custom initial date (not necessarily the 1st of January).

**Example :**

Let's say, I pick 08/05/2017 as my initial date, my quarters are going to be :

> 08/05/2017 - 07/08/2017
>
> 08/08/2017 - 07/11/2017
>
> 08/11/2017 - 07/02/2018
>
> 08/02/2018 - 07/05/2018
>
> and so on...

The resulting table will be like this :

[image: Result table]

Here's what I achieved so far :

```
SELECT 
    [Type], 
    CONVERT(date, DATEADD(QUARTER, TAB4.PeriodOffset, '08/05/2017')) AS [Periode], 
    SUM([Montant]) AS [Montant]
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        [Type],
        DATEDIFF(QUARTER, '08/05/2017', [Date]) AS [PeriodOffset]
        [Montant]
    FROM
    ( 
        --Data
    ) TAB3
) TAB4
GROUP BY TAB4.PeriodOffset, TAB4.[Type]
```

The problem here, is that `DATEDIFF(QUARTER, '08/05/2017', [Date])` compares dates based on the standard quarters (starting with the 1st of January, 1st of April, 1st of July and the 1st of October). Which means that `DATEDIFF(QUARTER, '08/05/2017', '08/07/2017')` is equal to 1 (because 08/05/2017 is in the second standard quarter and 08/07/2017 is in the third) while I need it to be equal to 0 (because 08/05/2017 and 08/07/2017 belong to the same quarter if we start with 08/05/2017). And here's what I get :

[image]

Comment: Make another table to define your custom periods (start date, end date, periodnumber or something similar). Then join your query to the periods table.

Comment: The starting date is not always the same, and the data can have thousands of rows. I can't afford to make a new table every time I want to run the query.

Comment: so in your case..is a quarter 90 days? or just startdate+3months-1day?

Comment: @vkp It's start date + 3 months - 1 day. And of course, 3 months is not 90 days, it depends on the starting date.

Comment: Are you sure you can't have your query make even a temp table to define the periods and then join it in? I think that's a solid option here. Do you need the "custom start date" to be a user input or is it based on the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to generate the custom start and end dates using a recursive cte. Thereafter, `left join` on to this table to get the desired result.

```
with quarter_dates(startdate,enddate) as 
(select cast('2017-05-08' as date),cast(dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month,3,'2017-05-08')) as date)
 union all
 select dateadd(month,3,startdate),dateadd(month,3,enddate) 
 from quarter_dates
 where startdate <'2020-12-01' --change this value based on the last startdate required
)
select d.startdate,d.enddate,y.type,sum(y.montant)
from quarter_dates d
left join yourtable y on y.periode between d.startdate and d.enddate
group by d.startdate,d.enddate,y.type
```

Comment: Being a complete CTE illiterate, this was very helpful (although I'm still trying to figure out how that works). Thank you and thanks to Jacob H for suggesting the same solution.